# Spring Boot - Should I implement multi-threading to resolve this problem?

Tags: java, spring, process, cypress

I've been working on some web project and one of its requests execute command line using Java Process.

This is the method.

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/startTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String startTest(int test_id) {
        ...

        String cmd = "..."

        ProcessUtil pu = new ProcessUtil();
        try {
            pu.execute(cmd);
            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                    + "\\datas\\cypress\\videos\\examples\\main.spec.js.mp4");
            File fileToMove = new File(
                    ".\\\\datas\\\\results\\" + uitest.getTest_filename() + ".mp4");
            file.renameTo(fileToMove);
            return "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "fail";
        }
    }
```

And Here is the ProcessUtil.java

```
public class ProcessUtil {
    
    public static void execute(String cmd) {

        Process process = null;
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        StringBuffer successOutput = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer errorOutput = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader successBufferReader = null; 
        BufferedReader errorBufferReader = null; 
        String msg = null; 

        List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (System.getProperty("os.name").indexOf("Windows") > -1) {
            cmdList.add("cmd");
            cmdList.add("/c");
        } else {
            cmdList.add("/bin/sh");
            cmdList.add("-c");
        }
        cmdList.add(cmd);
        String[] array = cmdList.toArray(new String[cmdList.size()]);

        try {
            
            process = runtime.exec(array);
            successBufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            while ((msg = successBufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                successOutput.append(msg + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            errorBufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8"));
            while ((msg = errorBufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                errorOutput.append(msg + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            process.waitFor();

            if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
                System.out.println("success!");
                System.out.println(successOutput.toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println("fail...");
                System.out.println(successOutput.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                process.destroy();
                if (successBufferReader != null)
                    successBufferReader.close();
                if (errorBufferReader != null)
                    errorBufferReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The problem that I'm facing is when I open two Windows command windows and execute simultaneously it seemingly works fine. However, when I run that 'startTest' method by requesting to my server simultaneously, it pushes my CPU and RAM to nearly 100% and results seemed odd. I don't know much about multi-threading, but I guess I should execute the command via multiple windows(I think my commands were executed in the same environment and they crashed each other...). Please give me some advice to resolve this problem... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seeing as each request already executes in its own thread I doubt adding more would help. Does it run fine when only calling `startTest` once?

Comment: @Erik Karlstrand Oh.. I forgot to mention that. Calling one startTest perfectly works fine. Could you explain more on 'adding more'? What else should I add on that method?

Comment: I was referring to adding more threads. Anyway, I believe that your problem lies within the use of `Runtime`. No matter how many threads used your application will only have one instance of `Runtime` and I'm lead to believe that the `Process` returned when calling `runtime.exec(array);` might be the same process. I'd try to create a unit test where two or more threads try to execute a simple command.

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand When I print out thread id(Thread.currentThread().getId()) of each requests, it returns different values(550, 559). I guess multi-threading is already implemented on my app because of spring boot. I think my problem is because I run on this with low CPU and RAM.

Comment: It's not Spring Boot that implements multi-threading by default. It's rather the nature of a web service that each request will execute in its own thread. Otherwise such applications would suffer horrible throughput.